# How do I delete a JSON Object key from the D JSON type?

Tags: d

The documentation doesn't have `myjson.remove(key)` or similar.

How would I delete a key from a json object without recreating the json object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so by accessing the internal object:

```
myjson.object.remove(key);
```